# Sharing a VPN connection

Tags: linux, networking, macos, vpn

There are similar question to this but none seem to give a direct answer to my question.

**Goal:** Connect to a Windows machine behind a L2TP/IPSec VPN using RDP from a Linux machine that doesn't support this type of VPN.

I have an L2TP/IPSec VPN configured on my mac mini. I can connect to the windows machine in question locally if I configure the VPN connection to send all traffic through it (without enabling this setting I can't connect). I can connect to the mac mini via SSH while the VPN connection is active.

Is it possible for me to tunnel, proxy, or otherwise route my (hopefully just RDP) traffic from the linux machine to the mac mini in a manner that allows me to connect to the windows machine?

**Additional info:**

- The linux machine doesn't have the ability to connect to the mac mini over Wi-Fi.

Comment: What's the version of linux? I would be very surprised that a Linux kernel would not have support for a VPN technology from well over a decade ago.

Comment: It is not that it doesn't have support, it's that I haven't been able to configure it. Strongswan seems to not allow PSK of less than 20 characters. The PSK on the VPN I want to connect to is less, and isn't something I can change.